# Can I create a single object that's accessible by different methods?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssound

This might be a basic question, but I'm new to Cocoa and Objective-C and OOP in general, and I haven't been able to find an answer to this anywhere.

In an app I'm writing, I want to play a sound file whenever the user presses a particular button.  I'm using NSSound for that and have no problem implementing it.  The problem is, I only know how to do it by creating a new NSSound object each time the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
    NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:kSoundFilePath byReference:YES];
    [sound play];
}
```

This is an issue for me because if the user clicks the button repeatedly before the file finishes playing, it will create new instances of NSSound and they will all play on top of each other, which I don't want.   Is there a way that I can create the NSSound object outside of that method, and have the IBAction method for the button check to see if the NSSound is playing before telling it to play again?

Comment: What about a sharedInstance/singleton?

Comment: That's not a good approach here. He wants to store the variable after its created, not allow only one sound object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yessir. This can be done several ways. One easy way is to use a private property:

```
/* these are in the SAME FILE */
@interface MyClass ()

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSound *sound;

@end

@implementation MyClass

    - (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
        self.sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:kSoundFilePath byReference:YES];
        [self.sound play];
    }

@end
```

You can also do it this way. **EDIT:** As Avt stated in the comments, there are some issues when using a global variable in his fashion. If you *ever* will be creating multiple instances of this class, you might be better off using a [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). To explain, here's [an article by the venerable Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com/c-storage-classes/).

```
@implementation MyClass

    NSSound *sound;

    ...

    - (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
        sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:kSoundFilePath byReference:YES];
        [sound play];
    }

@end
```

I personally use the first way because it makes it more clear from a programming standpoint that your class owns the created object. Though the second way is legal, it is less clear where the object belongs... it could be a local variable in the method's scope, or something else. I *would highly recommend* the first way, but in the interest of education you should know about all possible ways.

Comment: In addition to creating a property you can check if the sound is still playing when the action is send with - (BOOL)isPlaying

Comment: Very true, but I won't change the code... I think that that's beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: -1 because this is not solving author's problem. The same as before you are creating new NSSound object and play it. You save it to property but saved object is never used.

Comment: Thanks very much SevenBits, that's exactly what I wanted to know.  And especially thank you for teaching me the word mollycoddle.

Comment: @Avt Please explain to me how the property is not being used. I'm saving the object to a property, and the object saved is then being called.

Comment: @Cory that's what I plan on doing now that I'll be able to refer to a single instance of NSSound.  The problem before was that I was creating a new NSSound object each time, so I had no way to check if the last object was still playing.

Comment: @Avt this actually did answer my question.  I can add the code to check 'isPlaying' myself, I just didn't know how to get the point where I could do it

Comment: @nonex Could you upvote this post? Avt downvoted it for no reason, and wrongly so since this is the correct answer.

Comment: @SevenBits I tried, but I only have 13 reputation and I need 15 to be able to upvote anything.  I'll come back and upvote it when I get more rep.

Comment: In the second example `NSSound *sound;` declares a global variable, not a property. Global variables are not the best way to use here.

Comment: I didn't say that it was using a property; I said it was another way of doing the same thing. Then I stated that the way using properties is better, because yes, global variables are not very nice guys.

Comment: "Shoot yourself is not a nice idea but I will explain you how to do it". Global variable here will cause bugs if author will create 2 instances of his ViewController. So it is a serious defect of an answer.

Comment: We shouldn't just give code samples: our goal should be to educate. To educate how to write nice, bug-free code.

Comment: You're just shooting my comment on yours back at me, eh? ;) But I'll edit my answer to include your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Up at the declaration of your class, which should look something like this:

```
@implementation MyViewController
```

Add this:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
  NSSound* sound;
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad:

```
sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:kSoundFilePath byReference:YES];
```

And finally:

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
    [sound play];
}
```